# simple way to calculate average using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table where some inputs have to be insert to calculate average of certain numbers and null values have to be excluded. I have almost done it but stuck in the middle. Here are the codes:

```js
function calcAvg(input_id, output_id, co_id) {
  //Get all elements with 'class="select"'
  var selects = document.getElementsByClassName(input_id);
  //Initialize vars
  var avg = 0;
  var count = 0;
  //Calculate average
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    if (selects[i].value != "") {
      count++;
      avg += Number(selects[i].value);
      //Alert for debugging purposes
      //alert(selects[i].value+" "+avg);
    }
  }
  avg = avg / count;
  //Output average
  document.getElementById(output_id).value = avg;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="41" colspan="12" align="center">ATTAINMENT OF PO( PO-CO MAPPING)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="17%" rowspan="2" align="center">NAME OF THE MODULES</td>
    <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">PROGRAME OUTCOMES</td>
    <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">MODULE CO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO1</td>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO2</td>
    <td width="7%" align="center">CO AVERAGES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">MATHEMATICS</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1','calc_co1');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2','calc_co1');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Module_co1" id="calc_co1" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">SCIENCE</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1','calculation1','calc_co2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2','calculation2','calc_co2');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Module_co2" id="calc_co2" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
    <td height="71" align="center">PO AVERAGES</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg" id="calculation1" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg1" id="calculation2" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I have to calculate the average both vertically and horizontally. I have calculated horizontally but stuck in the the vertically calculation. The logic is- the value which are inserted in the vertical position will be the same. I know that the average will be same as the input value but i have to show it in the text box. If there any way to calculate it vertically...here also null value should be excluded.

Comment: Your indentation is really messy and hard to follow. This would be a much nicer question just by improving your code format. Also, there is no `type="text/jscript"`. I don't know any browser that would actually evaluate a `<script>` with that type.

Comment: edited....So i think i have missed document.getElementById(co_id).value=avg;

Comment: Note that right now, when I run your code, I get an error because `calc_co1` is not defined. I believe that should be in quotes, like `calcAvg('select1','calculation1',`calc_co1`);`, but didn't know if you meant to do that or not.

Comment: yes you are right i have done it and its working.

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you mean by "horizontally" and "vertically". When I run your code, I get the average of the elements by column, which is what I would term "vertically". Basically, the logic for "horizontally" is the same; add up the values of each input in the row and divide by the number of elements. Where are you stuck?

Comment: i have missed the getElementById statements therefore it was not working..Now it is working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to average the vertical and horizontal directions separately. You can create classes to indicate which row and column the input is in and then use that to call `calcAvg()` when any of the selects are changed.

I changed the class names of the selects and the ids of the average boxes, so it's a little more clear. For each select, `calcAvg()` is called twice, once for the vertical direction and once for the horizontal direction.

```js
function calcAvg(input_id, output_id) {
  //Get all elements with 'class="select"'
  var selects = document.getElementsByClassName(input_id);
  //Initialize vars
  var avg = 0;
  var count = 0;
  //Calculate average
  for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    if (selects[i].value != "") {
      count++;
      avg += Number(selects[i].value);
      //Alert for debugging purposes
      //alert(selects[i].value+" "+avg);
    }
  }
  avg = avg / count;
  //Output average
  document.getElementById(output_id).value = avg;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td height="41" colspan="12" align="center">ATTAINMENT OF PO( PO-CO MAPPING)
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="17%" rowspan="2" align="center">NAME OF THE MODULES</td>
    <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">PROGRAME OUTCOMES</td>
    <td height="34" colspan="11" align="center">MODULE CO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO1</td>
    <td width="7%" align="center">PO2</td>
    <td width="7%" align="center">CO AVERAGES</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">MATHEMATICS</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1v select1h" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1v','avg1v');calcAvg('select1h', 'avg1h');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2v select1h" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2v','avg2v');calcAvg('select1h','avg1h');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Module_co1" id="avg1h" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="71" align="center">SCIENCE</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select1v select2h" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select1v','avg1v');calcAvg('select2h','avg2h');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="number" class="select2v select2h" name="value[]" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==2) return false;" onChange="calcAvg('select2v','avg2v');calcAvg('select2h','avg2h');" style="width:60px">&nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Module_co2" id="avg2h" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr bgcolor="#9999CC">
    <td height="71" align="center">PO AVERAGES</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg" id="avg1v" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="Avg1" id="avg2v" readonly style="width:60px">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```